# Unable to open dynamically created two Dojo DateTextBox controls (StartDate, EndDate) inside a popup, Issue with IE browser

Tags: dojo

Following is the content for my popup control (dynamic). I'm facing issue with opening the calender control's of `DateTextbox` one after another. Issue exists in IE (version 10 I'm using) browser only, not in Chrome or Firefox. If I have only one `DateTextbox` inside a popup then I couldn't find any issues.

```javascript
var reportContainer = new TableContainer(
{
    cols: 1,
    customClass: "labelsAndValues",
    "labelWidth": "100"
}, dojo.byId("divForm"));

var startDateTextBox = new DateTextBox(
    {
        label: "Start Date :",
        id: "txtStartDate",
        name: "startDate",
        required: true,
        value: new Date()
    }, "startDate"
);

var endDateTextBox = new DateTextBox(
    {
        label: "End Date :",
        id: "txtEndDate",
        name: "endDate",
        required: true,
        value: new Date()
    }, "endDate"
);

reportContainer.addChild(endDateTextBox);
reportContainer.addChild(startDateTextBox);

reportContainer.startup();
```

As far as I analyzed, the method `_getDisplayedValueAttr` in the `_DateTimeTextBox.js` file causing the trouble. It executes recursively.

Is anyone having idea about this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess **browser caching** would be the reason for this problem, can you try the activity once after cleared the browser cache?